# Get route for base class of STI class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a rails app with 3 models, Person, Place and Thing.  Say the Thing uses single table inheritance, so there are FancyThing and ScaryThing subclasses.  Then there are routes defined with `map.resources :people, :places, :things`.  So there are no controllers for FancyThings and ScaryThings, the ThingsController handles either type.

Now say I need to have code that shows a list of anything has links to them.  If I have this code in my view:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= link_to item.name, item %>
<% end %>
```

If item is a Person or a Place, this works fine, `polymorphic_path` takes care of generating the correct route.  But if item is a FancyThing or a ScaryThing, this blows up, because it will try to use `fancy_thing_path`, which there is no route for.  I want to somehow make it use `thing_path`.  Ideally there would be a method on Thing and/or its subclasses that somehow indicates the subclasses should use the base class to generate the route.  Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: This is an [open ticket](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/10454) on rails development. See the ticket for suggestions on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<% @items.map {|i| if i.class < Thing then i.becomes(Thing) else i end}.each do |item| %>
  <%= link_to item.name, item %>
<% end %>
```

This uses the ActiveRecord function "becomes" to do an "up-cast" of all subclasses of Thing to the Thing base class.

Comment: This solution is about 10x as elegant as I was expecting.

Answer (score 8):

Try using

```
map.resources :things
map.resources :fancy_things, :controller => 'things'
map.resources :scary_things, :controller => 'things'
```

Comment: +1 For two reasons 1)This works for me. 2)This answer looks more dryer than the one accepted by @pjb3. Thanks.

Comment: This solution works, but has the down-side that it doesn't enforce the class/type , e.g. if you query an id via http://localhost:3000/fancy_things/21 and that item is actually from another sub-class ScaryThings, you would still get a valid response.  It should actually give an error, because it's not of class FancyThings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a correct answer, but at least I can deal with this problem using non-DRY code :

map.resources :things, :has_many => :stuffs
map.resources :fancy_things, :controller => 'things', :has_many => :stuffs
map.resources :scary_things, :controller => 'things', :has_many => :stuffs

Hope the issue will be soon corrected in edge, since I'd like to see fancy_things only manage by :things controller. Using these routes, you will end with urls like : /fancy_things/1 whereas you maybe want /things/1